# Exclude the first instance of each id

Tags: sas

I have a data set with an agent id and five other columns.
AgentID is a numeric value and contains multiple rows for different dates (order date). I want to exclude the first instance of the agent id in sas.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should post what you've tried. Have you looked at BY group processing and First. operations?

Answer (score 0):

This code excludes the oldest observation of each AgentID.

```
data have;
    format AgentID 8. OrderDate date9.;
    do AgentID = 1 to 2;
        do OrderDate = '01MAR2016'd to '05MAR2016'd;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by AgentID;
    if first.AgentID then delete;
run;
```

Comment: You should probably add `ORDERDATE` to the `BY` statement. That way SAS will complain if the observations within a single AgentID value are not ordered by date.